# Split method giving unexpected output

Tags: python, csv

I read a line as below from a CSV file:

```
GsmUart: enabled    2015-08-13T16:57:14.558000    0.072651
```

Note, each of these entries in the line were delimited by `'\t'` when the CSV was written.

**Problem: I want to extract the `0.072651`.**

I've tried:

- `print(str(line))` gives the entire line.
- `line.split('\t')[1].split('\t')[0]` gives the timestamp in between.
- `line.split('\t')[1].split('\t')[1]` gives `IndexError: list index out of range`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first `line.split('\t')` has already split on all the tabs so there are no more to split on in your second call, that means you only have one element in the list that the second `.split('\t')` returns giving you an `IndexError` trying to index a non existent second element.

what you want is the last element from the first split to get `0.072651`:

```
line.split('\t')[-1]
```

You could also use the csv module to read your file passing a tab as the delimiter:

```
import  csv

with open("your_file") as f:
    r = csv.reader(f,delimiter="\t")
    for a,b,c in row: 
        # ...
```

Comment: I feel stupid. line.split('\t')[2] did the job, thanks!

Comment: @xMaster, no worries, if all your data is tab delimited and you have three columns, you can use the csv module as in the last part to do the splitting